# Android Studio Start another activity from progress bar

Tags: android

I recently created a progress bar for my android studio game app , and it moves fine but i want it to start the second activity when the progress bar reaches 100. I don't know where to put and i don't want to make a mistake and then have to start my code all over again . So can someone help me on what to do ? This is my MainActivty.Java file (This is where the progress is).

```
package com.example.brandon.territories;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private ImageView ImageView;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //Long operation by thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 4;
                //Update progress bar with completion of operation
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 300 milliseconds.
                    //Just to display the progress slowly
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

class MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar
{
    public MyProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProgress(int progress)
    {
        super.setProgress(progress);
        if(progress == this.getMax())
        {
            //Do stuff when progress is max
            Intent intent  = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items
    //to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: use `private MyProgressBar progressBar` instead of `private ProgressBar progressBar`

Comment: Doesn't work @sulphur

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a simple AsyncTask and launch your new Activity from the onPostExecute method which is called when the background task ends?

An example:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> myAsyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           Log.d(TAG, "doing some work in background");
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    publishProgress(i);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            Log.d(TAG, "update progress bar here: " + values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "finishing background work, can start activity here");
        }
};
myAsyncTask.execute();
```

Comment: I wouldn't know where to put anything so i won't do it

Comment: If you send me your computer, I can write the code for you and send it back, as it seems you don't want to try by yourself to understand a so simple sample code.

Comment: I do but i don't want to try it and i don't know where anything goes .

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it, You can simply make a custom implementation of the ProgressBar and override the setProgress method:

```
class MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar
{
   @Override
   public void setProgress(int progress)
   {
       super.setProgress(progress);
       if(progress == this.getMax())
       {
          //Do stuff when progress is max
            Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
       }
   }
}
```

Just add above code snippet to your MainActivity and have fun.

Comment: On the first line , do i  put : public (The id of my progress bar) extends AppCompatActivity ? Because im getting errors .

Comment: can you please update the code you are now using in question along with the error

Comment: I am getting this error :       class MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar
there is a red line under the whole line .

Comment: hover on that red line, and an error msg will appear, please post it

Comment: There is no default constructor available in 'android.widget.ProgressBar'

Comment: Now im not getting any errors but it's not working .

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

by:

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar pgsBar;
    private int i = 0;
    private TextView txtView;
    private Handler hdlr = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pgsBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


                i = pgsBar.getProgress();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (i < 100) {
                            i += 1;
                            // Update the progress bar and display the current value in text view
                            hdlr.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    pgsBar.setProgress(i);
                                    txtView.setText(i+"%");
                //  or              txtView.setText(i+"/"+pgsBar.getMax());
                                    if( i == 100)
                                    {
                                        //Do stuff when progress is max
                                        Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                            try {
                                // Sleep for 100 milliseconds to show the progress slowly.
                                Thread.sleep(30);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();


    }

/*
    class MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar
    {
        public MyProgressBar(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void setProgress(int progress)
        {
            super.setProgress(progress);
            if(progress == this.getMax())
            {
                //Do stuff when progress is max
                Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Simple like that!

```
if( i == 100)
                                    {
                                        //Do stuff when progress is max
                                        Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
```